# Using an iterator in a recursive function results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list, recursion, iterator, segmentation-fault

I wrote a program that takes in N test cases of integers representing skill levels of students and attempts to find the total number of the smallest group possible if the only restriction is that there can be no to skill levels that are equal on a team and there is no skill gap greater than 1. So the following test case:

```
4 5 2 3 -4 -3 -5
```

would output:

```
3
```

Because the teams possible are {-4,-3,-5} and {4,5,2,3}, since the first group is only three members the output is 3.

I decided to use a linked list and a recursive function to solve the problem. One recursive function would go left and right of an integer looking for an integer that was higher by one size, is one is found then the element is removed from the list and 1 is returned. The same is done with another function looking for an integer smaller by 1. This should result in the sum of a group and I could compare the different sums to find the smallest. Unfortunately when I tried to implement this not only do I get a segmentation fault but the number that comes out after a few iterations are not even a part of the list and really large.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int findHigherSkillLevel(int skillLevel, list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;

  if (**it == (skillLevel + 1)) {
    //cout << "test3" << endl;
    skillLevel++;
    list.erase(*it); 
    *it = list.begin();   
    //cout << "Iterator in the higher skill level function if it finds a skill level higher by 1: " << **it << endl;
    //cout << "The skill level is: " << skillLevel << endl;
    return 1 + findHigherSkillLevel(skillLevel, it, list);
  } else {
    //cout << "Iterator in the higher skill level function if it doesn't find one: " << **it << endl;
    return findHigherSkillLevel(skillLevel, ++it, list);
  }

  return 0;
}

int findLowerSkillLevel(int skillLevel, list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;

  if (**it == (skillLevel - 1)) {
    skillLevel--;
    list.erase(*it);
    *it = list.begin();
    return 1 + findLowerSkillLevel(skillLevel, ++it, list);
  } else {
    //cout << "test2" << endl;
    return findLowerSkillLevel(skillLevel, ++it, list);
  }

  return 0;
}

int findGroupsSizes(list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;
  int groupSize = 1;
  int skillLevel = **it;
  *it = list.erase(*it);
  //cout << "Iterator value in the first function: " << **it << endl;
  groupSize += findHigherSkillLevel(skillLevel, it, list) + findLowerSkillLevel(skillLevel, it, list);

  return groupSize;
}
```

If I were to use the test case mentioned then it would iterate through 4, then 5, then 2, and then some weird numbers pop out and finally a seg fault. Is it impossible to use iterators on recursive functions if you pop them from the list in those recursions?

main() actually takes in t total test cases followed by t lines of N separated integers. I used the following as a test case:

```
4  
7 4 5 2 3 -4 -3 -5  
1 -4  
4 3 2 3 1  
7 1 -2 -3 -4 2 0 -1
```

Here is main if it matters:

```
int main() {
  int t; // the number of test cases
  cin >> t;
  vector<list<int> > skillLevels(t, list<int>());
  // input for each test case
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    int n; // number of students for this test case
    cin >> n;

    // initialize the list for this test case
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
       int skillLevel;
       cin >> skillLevel;
       skillLevels[i].push_back(skillLevel);
    }
  }

  // recursively scan lists for smallest teams
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    int minGroupNumber = skillLevels[i].size();
    list<int>::iterator iterator = skillLevels[i].begin();
    int skillLevel = skillLevels[i].front();

    while (!skillLevels[i].empty()) {
      iterator = skillLevels[i].begin();
      int currentGroupSize = findGroupsSizes(&iterator, skillLevels[i]);
      cout << currentGroupSize << endl; 
      if (currentGroupSize < minGroupNumber)
        minGroupNumber = currentGroupSize;
      //cout << minGroupNumber << endl;
      if (!skillLevels[i].empty()) skillLevels[i].pop_front();
    }
    cout << minGroupNumber << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The iterator returned by `erase` may be beyond the end, if you remove the last element, but you don't check before dereferencing it.

Comment: By the way, your recursion is pointless. It's all tail recursion and it could be replaced by a simple loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++it` is incrementing the pointer (which makes it invalid) not the iterator. You probably want `++*it`.

But that might also take you beyond the end of the list.

Comment: This seems to be working now as it's producing the numbers correctly as I print them out, but also like you mentioned this time it's going beyond the list. Is there are way to effectively make sure it doesn't iterate past the end point? I tried using (*it == list.end()) to make sure it stops but it seems to keep going...